# Subdomain to remote server

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, remote-server

I'm running a site on an apache server named `www.example.com` which has `sub.example.com` subdomain. Also I have a vps, which is accessable through `x.x.x.x` IP adress. `sub.example.com` is redirected to `x.x.x.x` with htaccess So I can reach my files on `x.x.x.x` through `sub.example.com`.

Everything is ok with this. But I want to solve this issue with DNS. How can I achieve that?

I'm using cpanel on www.example.com.

I searched a lot about that issue and find some information but I'm not fully aware of DNS settings. So I need a step by step guide.

Comment: Well if sub.example.com already points to x.x.x.x in the DNS zone, what more do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the DNS entry for `sub.example.com` and modify the A record to `x.x.x.x`.

On your vps, update apache config to host the domain `sub.example.com`. Configure a name based virtual host.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should i edit httpd.conf or editing htaccess is enough? And one more question. is it posibble to set x.x.x.x host config just for a spesific folder only for subdomain. Because I'm using the vps with a friend.

Comment: Yes, you can configure different folders for different sites (I guess thats what you want). You need to look into name based virtual hosts. And it involves editing apache's config files (including httpd.conf) and not just .htaccess.